# An alert after closing popup, fine with Chrome and Firefox, but problems with IE

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer

```
<script>
var openDialog = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
    var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
    var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
        try {
            if (win == null || win.closed) {
                window.clearInterval(interval);
                closeCallback(win);
            }
        }
        catch (e) {
        }
    }, 1000);

    return win;
};

var test = function() {
    alert(bye);
};

openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", test);
</script>
```

This is code to show an alert after closing popup. It works fine in Chrome and Firefox, but has a problem in IE. In IE, the popup opens, and before closing it, the alert comes up. How can I fix it? I want to show the alert after closing the popup. Thank you.

Comment: you attach an event listener to the window you open. eg. $(win).on("unload", callbackFunction); that fires your alert

Comment: I want to open external URL page on my popup, so I'm afraid I can't attach that code to my window I open. Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't probe objects to see if they exist every x seconds. Attach events with a callback function, then you only fire an event once, when you actually need to and not a million times before.

Try:

```
var openDialog = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
    var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
    win.addEventListener("onunload", test);

};

var test = function() {
    alert(bye);
};
```

this should fire your alert when the window closes, enjoy

Comment: <script>
 var openDialog = function(uri, name, options, closeCallback) {
    var win = window.open(uri, name, options);
    win.addEventListener("onunload", test);

};

var test = function() {
    alert('bye');
};

openDialog("//google.com", "popup", "scrollbars=no", test);
</script>

Comment: By this, I can't get an alert. I think there is something wrong. Anyway, thank you.